# My guitar is tuned half step down how can I play along a standard tuned song?

Tags: guitar, tuning

I would like to play along some Deep Purple songs from time to time but my guitar is tuned to E flat and I find it unhandy to tune it to standard E tuning and then back to E flat tuning.

Given I have only one guitar, is there a way I can shift the pitch of the song half step down?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just transpose it a half step down?

Comment: 1. Use a capo on the first fret, then your guitar is in standard tuning. 2. Get a second guitar. 3. Pitch down the tunes you want to play along with (e.g., with [Audacity](http://audacityteam.org/) ).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are pieces of software available that can transpose pieces of music (I used to use Adobe Audition, although it did take a long time for the software to export the transposed music).

Alternatively, you could use a capo on fret 1 and play as you normally would, only 1 fret higher. If you're not playing chords (or if you're good at bar-chords) you could just play 1 fret higher without the use of a capo.

Comment: You covered it.  Plus 1. Audacity linked in a comment above by Matt L. is a free software program that will quickly and easily transpose your audio file to a different key.  I keep my guitar tuned half step flat and use Audacity to transpose backing tracks that come in standard tuning. But if I just want to play along and not sing, I put a capo on first fret (or whichever fret is needed to be in tune with the record).